# How can I move columns to the right in a Highcharts chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a column chart with Highcharts library, something like this:

[image: chart]

If you see the red lines maybe you notice what I want achieve. I need to reduce the space between columns and move them to the right, so the chart will have more space between the y-labels and the first column.

Notice that I need a fixed width of 48px for every column. I tried with with `groupPadding : 0` and `pointPadding : 0` with no luck.

```
plotOptions : {
    series : {
        colorByPoint : true,
        pointWidth : 48,
        borderWidth : 0,
    }
},
```

All the sample code is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgypy32h/3/).

How can I move all the columns to the right and reduce the space between columns?

**UPDATE:** As an answer says, a solution is to change the container width to a smaller one. But I need that the grid lines (the grey ones) fill all the page (actually, fill the parent div that would have more width than the chart container). Is it possible to draw the grey lines (the grid lines) *outside* the chart?

Comment: Hi. maybe this will work for you. The idea is to push null values before your data. This will move all the collumns to the right and will reduce the space between them. http://jsfiddle.net/x6djt6c7/

Comment: @HristoIvanov It could work (in fact, It seems that work) but I think I would prefer another *better* solution.

Comment: @HristoIvanov finally it seems that I have to use your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've done what @HristoIvanov told me in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198049/how-can-i-move-columns-to-the-right-in-a-highcharts-chart#comment44763203_28198049). They suggest that I should put `NULL` columns at the begining.

Setting the first categorie as `NULL` and not showing it, is what I need because highcharts left the space for the first column.

That's the code that I needed:

```
xAxis : {
    showFirstLabel: false,
    categories : [ null, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G' ],
    [ ... ]
```

And don't forget the data:

```
series : [
    { data : [null, 11, 22, 53, 74, 65, 46, 37] }
```

You can view the result in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgypy32h/9/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code was with a ","

Try this:

```
            plotOptions : {
                series : {
                    colorByPoint : true,
                    pointPadding : 0,
                    groupPadding : 0 
                }
            },
```

Here is your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zgypy32h/5/

http://jsfiddle.net/zgypy32h/4/

Comment: Sorry, I have not explained well. It doesn't work because I need that the columns have a 48px width.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like what you were going for: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgypy32h/7/)

There were a couple things that were giving you trouble. The chart by default wants to fill out the `div` it's in as much as possible because  of Highcharts default settings (check out the [reflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.reflow) option). So to keep the columns close together you have set a `max-width` or `width` on the container that you feel satisfies the spacing between columns.

```
<div id="container" style="max-width: 650px; height: 520px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

And give yourself a little more margin on the left of the chart to compensate.

```
chart : {
  renderTo : 'container',
  type : 'column',
  showAxes : true,
  marginRight : 0,
  marginLeft : 50,
  spacingLeft : 20,
  spacingRight : 0
},
```

The second is the [offset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset) of the y-axis labels to give some spacing between them and the first column. Highcharts doesn't seem to have an initial offset for the first x point, but `offset` should suffice.

```
yAxis: {
   offset: 60
}
```

Comment: Your solution could work, but, like in the picture I post, I need that the x axis lines fill all the container. I mean, I need a chart of 968px (for example) because I need that the x axis lines (the grey lines) fill the 968px. Is there a posibility to draw that lines outside the chart?